# How to make ~30 plots look good in one view

Tags: r

I'd like to plot 40 different plots in R.  How can I control the height and width of the plots so the x and y axis are readable?  It appears no matter what you set the hieght and width to the plots shrink in the plot viewport to sizes smaller than what you want.

Here is a toy example with 26 plots. I am using the multi plot function here:  http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/

```
PLOT_LIST= list()
c <-rep(letters[1:26], 1,each=26)
x = rep(1:26,26)
y = rep(1:26,26)
d<- data.frame(cbind(c,x,y))
head(d)
uniCat= as.character(unique(d[,1]))
uniCat
for (i in 1:length(uniCat)){
  #i=1
  temp= subset(d, c == uniCat[i] )
  PLOT_LIST[[i]]<- ggplot(temp, aes(x=x, y=y),height = 200, width= =200) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + ggtitle( uniCat[i])
}
multiplot(plotlist=PLOT_LIST, cols= 4)
```

Here you can see the output. The axis are unreadable. How can I fix the height and width so that it's consumable?height = 200, width= 200 does not seem to work.

Thank you.
[image]

Here is the multiplot function:

```
multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, file, cols=1, layout=NULL) {
  library(grid)

  # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
  plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)

  numPlots = length(plots)

  # If layout is NULL, then use 'cols' to determine layout
  if (is.null(layout)) {
    # Make the panel
    # ncol: Number of columns of plots
    # nrow: Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols
    layout <- matrix(seq(1, cols * ceiling(numPlots/cols)),
                     ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols))
  }

  if (numPlots==1) {
    print(plots[[1]])

  } else {
    # Set up the page
    grid.newpage()
    pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))

    # Make each plot, in the correct location
    for (i in 1:numPlots) {
      # Get the i,j matrix positions of the regions that contain this subplot
      matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))

      print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
                                      layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using `facet_grip` or `facet_wrap` in ggplot-http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/

Comment: You appear to be confused about building a plot object in R versus rendering it on a graphics device. The final size of the plot is determined at render time, not a build time. You have invented non-existent `width` and `height` arguments to `ggplot`. When you render via `print` at the console it will simply fill whatever open device you have or use whatever default size you have set. When you write to disk (png, pdf, etc.) you can control the size of the plot.

Comment: if you expect a plot with 26 graphs to be "readable" you're going to be in for a long day